# calculate the depth feature in kinect?

Tags: kinect, depth

I am learning how kinect works. But I am new to this field. somebody please help me , to better understand the given formula

Fϴ(I,x)=DI(x+(u/DI(x))-DI(x+(v/DI(x)))

In the description it is given that where 
dI (x) is the depth at pixel x in image I, and 
parametersϴ = (u, v) describe offsets u and v. 
The normalization of the offsets by 1/dI (x) ensures the features are depth invariant:at a given point on the body, a fixed world space offset will result whether the pixel is close or far from the camera.

I am still unable to understand the whole formula that what is the depth at pixel x, what are the offsets u,v , offsets u and v, normalization of offsets ,..please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pixel X and offset(U,V) are all vectors instead of numbers.

For example X is (100,200).
U is (5,0) V is (0,10).

And the normalization of offsets means if the point is near to the camera the offset is smaller, as the depth value in the near region is bigger. In the picture you can see, theta1 is bigger than theta2.
In that case, it will be depth invariable.

[image]